# CURL is not executing first time properly

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, curl

I am using below given code for getting the flight results from **Skyscanner API** from CURL using ajax in **cakephp 3**
and I am executing it in loop if there is more than one location's flight searched by user , so the problem is its not always returning all the flight result everytime until I refresh the page and when I refresh another ajax request calls with the same parameter and than I am getting all the results, I dont know why its not fetching all the result in first time please suggest me the best solution for this ,Thanks all for the help

```
$apiParamsUrl = "http://www.skyscanneraffiliate.net/portal/en-GB/UK/LivePricing/TestHarness?apikey=*******&country=GB&currency=GBP&locale=en-GB&originplace=".$origin."&destinationplace=".$destination."&outbounddate=".$routes['date']['start_date']."&adults=".$routes['no_of_traveller']['no_of_traveller']."&children=0&infants=0&locationschema=iata&cabinclass=economy&groupPricing=true";

$apiParamsStr = parse_url($apiParamsUrl, PHP_URL_QUERY); 

parse_str($apiParamsStr, $apiParamsArray); 
$apiSessionUrl = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $apiSessionUrl);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($apiParamsArray));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiParamsStr);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

if(!curl_exec($ch)){
    break; 
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~Location: ([^\s]+)~', $header, $matches);
```

Comment: why are you using `preg_match('~Location: ([^\s]+)~', $header, $matches);`???

Comment: @spirit its for matching some format,

Comment: I mean what is for you matching `Location` header?

Comment: @spirit it was in the given sample php code from skyscanner technical dept.

Comment: So, you don't use `$matches` variable at all?

Comment: I have print both the variable `$header` and `$matches` and it is coming result after `preg_match` line

Comment: HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 09:00:47 GMT
Location: http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk1/v1.0/cd4450995ba0460db8852730fc75dc05_ecilpojl_864D004A4543445A2A46F1A6A8BA7ADC
Content-Length: 2
Array
([0] => Location: http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk1/v1.0/cd4450995ba0460db8852730fc75dc05_ecilpojl_864D004A4543445A2A46F1A6A8BA7ADC
    [1] => http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk1/v1.0/cd4450995ba0460db8852730fc75dc05_ecilpojl_864D004A4543445A2A46F1A6A8BA7ADC)

Comment: do u think its effecting the things?

Comment: I suspect that that another ajax call is not the same. Could you show some more of your code? And add some punctuation to your question, it is not readable =)

Comment: actually when the page loads than the ajax calls for getting the flights response and when i refresh the page same ajax function calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120092/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-spirit).

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, I've changed it a little bit:

```
$apiParamsUrl = "http://www.skyscanneraffiliate.net/portal/en-GB/UK/LivePricing/TestHarness?apikey=*******&country=GB&currency=GBP&locale=en-GB&originplace=" . $origin . "&destinationplace=" . $destination . "&outbounddate=" . $routes['date']['start_date'] . "&adults=" . $routes['no_of_traveller']['no_of_traveller'] . "&children=0&infants=0&locationschema=iata&cabinclass=economy&groupPricing=true";

$apiParamsStr = parse_url($apiParamsUrl, PHP_URL_QUERY);

parse_str($apiParamsStr, $apiParamsArray);
$apiSessionUrl = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiSessionUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // <-- changed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiParamsStr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // <-- changed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // <-- added


$body = curl_exec($ch);
if (false === $body) {
    break;
}
curl_close($ch);

var_export($body);
```

Comment: if (false === $body) {
throw new RuntimeException('curl error. errno: '.curl_errno($ch).'. error: '.curl_error($ch));
}